# How many NUMA nodes on a Power8 processor

Tags: linux, cpu-architecture, numa, power-architecture

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 on a two sockets Power8 machine, each socket has 10 cores.  "numactl -H" outputs:

```
available: 4 nodes (0-3)
node 0 cpus: 0 8 16 24 32
node 0 size: 30359 MB
node 0 free: 26501 MB
node 1 cpus: 40 48 56 64 72
node 1 size: 0 MB
node 1 free: 0 MB
node 2 cpus: 80 88 96 104 112
node 2 size: 30425 MB
node 2 free: 27884 MB
node 3 cpus: 120 128 136 144 152
node 3 size: 0 MB
node 3 free: 0 MB
node distances:
node   0   1   2   3 
  0:  10  20  40  40 
  1:  20  10  40  40 
  2:  40  40  10  20 
  3:  40  40  20  10
```

The problem is, are there two NUMA nodes on each Power8 processor? Any why one has memory but the other one has nothing. I can't find any document about this. Any information would be appreciated.

A further question, if there are two nodes on a socket, then are their last level cache shared like NUMA nodes(a data can reside in all of the caches) or like on the same socket(only one copy can exist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scale-out POWER8 systems use Dual-Chip Modules (DCMs). As the name suggests, a DCM packages two multi-core chips with some additional logic within the same physical package. There is an on-package cache-coherent 32 GBps interconnect (misleadingly called an SMP bus) between the two chips and two separate paths to the external memory buffers, one for each chip. Thus, each socket is a dual-node NUMA system itself, similar to e.g., the multi-module AMD Opterons. In your case, all of the memory local to a given socket is probably installed in the slots belonging to the first chip of that socket only, therefore the second NUMA domain shows up as 0 MB.

Both the on-package (X bus) and inter-package (A bus) interconnects are cache-coherent, i.e. the L3 caches are kept in sync. Within a multi-core chip, each core is directly connected to a region of L3 cache and through the chip interconnect has access to all other L3 caches of the same chip, i.e. a NUCA (Non-Uniform Cache Architecture).

For more information, see the logical diagram of an S824 system in [this Redpaper](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp5097.pdf).